# What is the proper way to handle revert errors from requires checks for truffle testing?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I have a smart contract that implements OZ's onlyOwner modifier for several functions.  I am testing it using truffle and have written a unit test where a non-owner account calls an onlyOwner function.

```
it("non-owner cannot create race", async () => {
        const instance = await raceFactory.deployed();
        const race = await instance.createUpcomingRace({from: accounts[1]});
        assert.equal(????);
    });
```

The response is exactly what I wanted:
`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Ownable: caller is not the owner -- Reason given: Ownable: caller is not the owner.`

What is the correct way to catch this exception in the test above so that this error gives a passing test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `expectRevert` from [@openzeppelin/test-helpers](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers).

Example from GitHub:

```js
it('reverts when transferring tokens to the zero address', async function () {
    // Conditions that trigger a require statement can be precisely tested
    await expectRevert(
      // TX expected to revert
      this.erc20.transfer(constants.ZERO_ADDRESS, this.value, { from: sender }),
      // expected revert message
      'ERC20: transfer to the zero address',
    );
  });
```

For your code:

```js
it("non-owner cannot create race", async () => {
        const instance = await raceFactory.deployed();
        await expectRevert(instance.createUpcomingRace({from: accounts[1]}), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    });
```